# open a new window using middle click on icons on Dock

Tags: ubuntu-dock, nemo

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and Nemo.

How to make it open a new Nemo's window when I middle click the icon on the Dock?

It works for nautilus.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the Nemo's .desktop file lacks a "new-window" action.

Fix this by cloning the .desktop file to your user home, then replace the open-home action. e.g. from a terminal run:

```
mkdir --parents ~/.local/share/applications/
cp /usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
nano ~/.local/share/applications/nemo.desktop
```

Then Find this text:

```
Actions=open-home;open-computer;open-trash;

[Desktop Action open-home]
Name=Home
```

And change it to:

```
Actions=new-window;open-computer;open-trash;

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
```

Save, Log out and back in again.

Comment: This work not perfectly (in june 2023) but the idea is very good. .  Personally i made a copy of the nemo.desktop and have placed it on the desktop page.I made the changes there. When i want a second, or third etc. window i use this one.